# Does Kafka provides a way to interleave messages from multiple topics based on event timestamp, instead of doing it client-side?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have messages sitting in two Kafka topics. I have a consumer that needs messages from both topics in such a way that these messages are interleaved based on the timestamp in which these messages (i.e.: events) occurred.

Note that the occurrence of the event is not the same as the timestamp when the message was produced on the topic.

As an example, let's say I have 2 datafeeds of historic stock prices. Events (a price of a stock at a certain time) has already happened. I create 2 topics (1 for each datafeed) and insert all events in these 2 topics.

I now want to somehow subscribe to both topics, and receive interleaved prices of both datafeeds based on the order in which these stock prices actually changed.

A way to do this in the client would be to buffer prices from 1 feed, until a price from the other feed is received. This allows to compare timestamps and as a result allows me to push the correct 'next' event downstream.

I'd rather not have to do this clientside as these buffers might grow, and it's just not nice boilerplate.

is there any way to push this responsibility down to Kafka?

Comment: The kafka brokers are pretty dumb (on purpose). This kind of logic has to sit on the client. It might be worth for you to take a look at kafka streams as it has some feature to stich together messages from multiple topics, but that can be a painful rabbit hole.

Comment: When you produce an event, you can set whatever timestamp you want in the record itself. Records aren't ordered by time in any meaningful way